# Is it possible to do a Drush make custom installation profile?

Tags: drush, installation-profiles

Is is possible to make a selective Drush Make file?

For example:

The site has 3 modules, with 3 library files.

A normal drush make will give me all modules and files.

But it is possible to selectively, fetch some modules and files?

For example: fetch module 1 and file 1 but not 2 and 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the *OPTIONAL ATTRIBUTES*

**root_element[first_key][next_key] = value**

> The 'projects' attribute is where you define the modules/themes that 
>   are to be packaged with the profile. The first key is the short name 
>   of the project (as seen in the drupal.org/project/{projectshortname} 
>   URI).
>
> These projects are defined using the short form definition. You can
>   use this form if you only want to declare the version of the
>   project. The version is the value to the right of the core Drupal
>   version in a full version string. For example, if you wanted to
>   specify Views 7.x-3.1, you would use:

```
projects[views] = 3.1
```

> For pre-releases, like CTools 7.x-1.0-rc1, use this format:

`projects[ctools] = 1.0-rc1`

> You can also specify -dev releases of projects; however, this is 
>   generally NOT recommended, since it results in end users getting 
>   different sets of files at different times that distribution is 
>   built, which can cause confusing bug reports. If you really must use 
>   a -dev release, it's better to specify a Git revision (see below).

```
projects[media] = 2.x-dev
```

**Reference**

- [Full example drupal-org.make file](https://www.drupal.org/node/1432374).
- [Managing Drush make files for an installation profile](https://www.drupal.org/node/1476014).

Comment: That sounds good, but am I better with features? I want this for sites that are already set up with Aquica Dev Desktop. Can I create a "make" without the whole website? For example, a make that incorporates ONLY "ckeditor+IMCE+ their configuration settings" ? Is it possible, overkill? Features better?

Comment: @BrunoVincent if refers to the features modules vs drush make I think that you must open another question, because this is another explanation about the problem.